# Is a Biostar p4M890-M7 ver 7.0 compatible with intel slb9u?

Tags: cpu, motherboard, compatibility

Help with hardware compatibility.
Hello, my old motherboard is near to die and I'm about to buy a new one but I need something to stand on meanwhile.

It results that I have an old Biostar model p4m890-m7 TE ver 7.0 and I need to check if I can I upgrade the cpu for the Intel xeon E5200 model number SLB9U Dual core 2.6 Ghz 2M/800/06 that i was using,

It's been a long since I dont test cpu's and I'm not sure how to check if both parts are compatible.

as far as I search here https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Biostar/P4M890-M7_TE_7.x.html  I can't find that cpu model on the supported cpu's.

I tryied anyway to make the motherboard with that cpu and it couldn't boot but just to make sure I ask you here, may be it was another kind of error as that motherboard also doesn't go well with the memory sticks I have.

Comment: The socket needs to match, and the BIOS needs to support the CPU. You need to check the manufacturer data sheets and the latest BIOS release notes to see which CPUs are supported by a given mainboard. This information is available to you as readily as it is to us.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell - the motherboard supports LGA 775 - and your processor (which is a pentium 4), should fit, and presumably work.

That said - not only would be your motherboard and CPU be old, that's roughly at the tail end of the [capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague).

From experience I've also gotten 'memory errors' from a pent pin in the LGA socket, and checking for it is difficult if you don't know what you're looking for. (Shine a flashlight at the socket - a bent 'pin' won't be as shiny)

Considering the system is about 13 years old, finding parts (and information!) for it is going to be challenging as well. Pretty much the only 'contemporary' part you can still use is a PSU, and newer motherboards are moving off the old 'classic' ATX pinouts.

Even as a 'temporary' system, as its not running already it would very much be a case of throwing good time after bad in its current state.

Comment: About the capacitor plague, that's whjat happened to my last motherboad with a broken capacitor. I know that all this is a waste of time, but I don't wan't to buy stuff in urgence.